# JSON Load from link to use in scope

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using request module in express to load a json from a link.

```
var url = 'https://api.github.com/users/google/repos';

request.get({
    url: url,
    json: true,
    headers: {'User-Agent': 'request'}
}, (err, res, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error:', err);
    } else if (res.statusCode !== 200) {
    console.log('Status:', res.statusCode);
} else {
    // data is already parsed as JSON:
    console.log(data.length);
}
});
```

The output of console.log returns a length of 30.

How can i use the parsed JSON globally (data), outside the function? If i use `console.log(data.length)` outside it says

> Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Thank you!

Comment: You could just assign it to a global variable, but you may not know when the request has completed executing.

Comment: The data is available in the callback function and is available asynchronously and you can't just use it directly, please tell us what you want to do with it, so that another way could be suggested

Comment: i want after that to make a for and display on my index.ejs all the 30 names from the json.

Comment: You put the code in a function, and pass the loaded JSON as an argument. Then call that function in the request done method.

Comment: Are you using pure javascript or some sort of framework too

Comment: Pure JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
function AnyFunction(res){
//do what you want here 
console.log(res.length);
}

const options = {
  method: 'GET',
  uri: 'https://api.github.com/users/google/repos',
  json: true,
  headers: {'User-Agent': 'request'}
}
​
request(options)
  .then(function (response) {
    // Request was successful, use the response object at will
    console.log(response.length);
   //you can also pass it in a function and do whatever you want
   AnyFunction(response);
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    // Something bad happened, handle the error
    console.log('Error:', err);
  })
```